# Is there a way to check daily data transfer on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can see the monthly billing information. But is there any way to check daily data transfer on aws, especially s3 bucket relevant (I haven't the S3 logging functionality turned on at that time) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag the buckets and then use the tags in the billing to work out usage